# When will the value of the given variable resets to 0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I recently started learning nodejs and express and I fall into one problem. Can anyone will tell me when the value of variable `let i=0` resets to 0 in the given below code ?

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

const port = 3000
let i = 0;

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(""+ i++)
})

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

So you can see that after each page reload or when page get called, value of variable i increased by 1. So once again what are the required conditions so that it will reset to 0 ?

Comment: It will never reset to 0.

Comment: Only if you restart the server or reset it manually to 0.

Comment: it'll get to `9007199254740992` ... and that's where it stays - though, I doubt we'll be alive :p

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Well, That's not true. I turned off the server and it got reset.

Comment: the value won't reset, until you restart the server

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat everyone replied the same you answered.

Comment: @Bravo are you talking of infinity ?

Comment: @AlokPrakash - no, it won't get to infinity ... because `9007199254740992 + 1 = 9007199254740992`

Comment: OK, a more thorough answer - the value will reset to 0 in the following cases: 1. Your computer is shut down. 2. A cosmic ray corrupts your RAM. 3. A meteor hits the Earth. There are probably other cases, but these come to mind.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev All of your answer can be accepted. However, Probability of event of case 1 is more likely to occur. And case 2 is RAM corruption also good reason. If RAM corrupts then System will hang/shutdown. It means we have to restart server again. So, basically both are same.

Comment: @Bravo I tried to initialize i with 9007199254740991 but it never get incremented after 9007199254740992 . Also afterwards, It didn't got reset to 9007199254740991.

Comment: that's what I said ... it won't get past `9007199254740992` - and I never said ot would reset to  `9007199254740991` - thanks for incorrecting me though

Comment: @Bravo I didn't mean to incorrect you. I thought that it would be zero or some error after that but both not occurs. Thank You, for this case.

Comment: @AlokPrakash all good :p